# Rendered actions disappear when navigating back

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my masterpage I'm using a simple @Html.Action("", ""). This works fine but if I click any link (navigating away from the initial page) and then use the back button in my browser to navigate back, the action isn't rendered any more.

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

God I feel really stupid... for some reason the webpage is cached (even though my browser should check for new versions of the webpage always). I barely noticed but I saw that a color I changed reverted back to before I changed it every time I pressed the back button.

Sorry.